# Фильтрация файлов в папке по содержимому строк

Tags: cmd, bat

Есть директория с набором файлов. Файлы имеют одинаковую структуру. 1 строка заголовок всегда разная. Все последующие строки (одна или более) содержат информацию разделенную символом **^**.

Пример одного из файлов:

```
заголовок
1^4^63350^текст^текст^11.2016^7^0^6^2^^201^132^2004^SC^MS^^
1^1^63650^текст^текст^16.2056^7^0^6^2^^201^132^2004^SC^MS^^
1^2^65350^текст^текст^15.2046^7^0^6^2^^201^132^2004^SC^MS^^
1^8^63650^текст^текст^16.2056^7^0^6^2^^201^132^2004^SC^MS^^
1^2^65350^текст^текст^15.2046^7^0^6^2^^201^132^2004^SC^MS^^
```

**Задача:** оставить в папке только те файлы в которых начиная со второй строки, хотя бы в одной из строк, после первого символа ^ и перед вторым символом ^ есть цифра **2**. Остальные файлы удалить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1й вариант**
Если вам нужны только файлы, содержащие строки вида:

> 1^**2**^65350^текст^текст^15.2046^7^0^6^2^^201^132^2004^SC^MS^^

но не

> 1^**123**^65350^текст^текст^15.2046^7^0^6^2^^201^132^2004^SC^MS^^

(код сохранять как .cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: здесь укажите путь к файлам и маску для поиска
set files=D:\3\*.txt

for %%f in (%files%) do (
  set found=
  for /f "skip=1 tokens=2 delims=^^" %%l in (%%f) do if "%%l" equ "2" set found=1
  if "!found!" equ "" echo del /q %%f
)
```

**2й вариант**
Если вам нужны также файлы, в которых встречаются строки вида:

> 1^**123**^65350^текст^текст^15.2046^7^0^6^2^^201^132^2004^SC^MS^^

т.е. после первого символа ^ идёт любое число, содержащее двойку, то:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: здесь укажите путь к файлам и маску для поиска
set files=D:\3\*.txt

for %%f in (%files%) do (
  set found=
  for /f "skip=1 tokens=2 delims=^^" %%l in (%%f) do (
    echo %%l | find "2" > nul
    if "!errorlevel!" equ "0" set found=1
  )
  if "!found!" equ "" echo del /q %%f
)
```

P.S: Если всё работает как надо, то не забудьте удалить **echo** перед **del** для реального удаления файлов.

---

Кстати, если файлы большие, то можно использовать такой скрипт - он должен работать шустрее (только для первого варианта):

```
@echo off

:: здесь укажите путь к файлам и маску для поиска
set files=D:\3\*.txt

for %%f in (%files%) do call :check %%f
goto :eof

:check
for /f "skip=1 tokens=2 delims=^^" %%l in (%1) do if "%%l" equ "2" goto :eof
echo del /q %1
```

Comment: 1 вариант! Спасибо то, что нужно!

Comment: Добавил более шустрый (в теории) вариант.